# How do I generate a table with a border which contains borderless cells with fpdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, dynamically-generated

I can generate a table like this with fpdf in php:[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE6aQ.jpg)

I have been trying to do it, but it turns out there’s no way for defining a “table border” in fpdf or even selecting which border of the individual cells you’d like to display… at least that’s my impression.